# Geocoding doesn't work now V3 is in play

Tags: php, xml-parsing, geocoding

I have a internal site which uses php to look through my msql customer database. Find any customers which do not have lat and lng fields filled in. Grab the postcodes and geocode them posting the lat and lng back to my database and plot the customers on the map. This is done by a cron job once a day. This worked fine using v.2 of google api. Since march or april its stopped. Im guessing because of v.3.

Jist my jl_jobscoordinates.cron.php file searches through the database picking up all the postcodes for empty lat and lng fields. Then calls a function from my geocode.class.php called doGeocode which uses xml to put togther and find results and save the lat and lng. Inside the geocodeclass it refers to a m_url which is the googleapi url which is saved inside my config file. I have updated this url to the new v.3 url which is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%s&sensor=false. My map is back up and running, just nothing will geocode.

I will paste the two files jl_jobscooedinates.cron.php and geocode.class.php. I have commented out the old xml in the geocode which used to work with the old url.

The results of my cron is that it is not getting coordinates. e.g. -- [3-2013] Google could not find this Postcode: [COO041] Test Company Name, Oxfordshire OX26 4SS

jl_jobcoordinates.cron.php

```
require_once("../includes/config.php");     
require_once(_PATH_JMS."/classes/session.class.php");   
require_once(_PATH_JMS."/classes/db.class.php");
require_once(_PATH_JMS."/classes/lib.class.php");
require_once(_PATH_JMS."/classes/security.class.php");
require_once(_PATH_JMS."/classes/emails.class.php");
require_once(_PATH_JMS."/classes/geocode.class.php");

require_once(_PATH_JMS."/services/actiontrail.ds.php"); 
require_once(_PATH_JMS."/services/jobsdue.ds.php"); 

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Main Object Instances - Initialize what we require    
//-----------------------------------------------------

$DB             = new DB();
$Security       = new Security($DB->i_db_conn);
$Lib            = new Lib();
$Session        = new Session();
$ActionTrail    = new ActionTrail($DB, $Session, $Security);
$JobsDue        = new JobsDue($DB, $Session, $Security, $ActionTrail);
$Geocode        = new Geocode($Session, $Security);
$Emails         = new Emails($DB, $Session, $Security);

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Save as a valid system user   
//-----------------------------------------------------

$Session->save('USR_AUTH',_CRON_USER_NAME);
$Session->save('USR_PASS',_CRON_USER_PASS);
$Session->save('USR_IS_EMPLOYED', '1');
$Session->save('CONS',$Session->get('USR_AUTH'));

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Postcodes to Ignore - we cannot geocode these
//-----------------------------------------------------

$m_ignore = array("IRL","IRELAND","IRE","ITA","USA","BEL","EGY","GER","FR","FRA","HOL","POL");

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Get Jobs Due for all consultants for this year and next
//-----------------------------------------------------

$mY = (int) date("Y");

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Find t-cards without lat & lng
//-----------------------------------------------------

$m_errors = array();





for ($y=$mY;$y<=$mY+1;$y++) 
{
    for ($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) 
    {
        $mM = (int) $i; 
        //echo "<br> mM =".$mM ." i =".$i;  
        $mJobs = $JobsDue->getAllJobsDue('%',$mM,$y,'%',NULL,NULL,FALSE); /* DON'T GET MISSED JOBS AS WE WILL START FROM JAN */
        //echo "<br>mJobs =".$mJobs;
        foreach ($mJobs as $row)
        {
            $m_postcode = $Lib->lib_str_clean(trim($row->postcode)); //this loops through each of the records and gets the post codes. m_postcodes are the postcodes found
            echo "<br>m_postcode =".$m_postcode;
            if (($row->latlngexists == 1)||(in_array($m_postcode,$m_ignore))||(in_array($row->card_id,$m_ignore))||(strlen($m_postcode)<=0)) continue;
            if ($Lib->lib_ispostcode($m_postcode)) {
                $m_coordinates = $Geocode->doGeocode($m_postcode);
                echo "<br>m_coords =".$m_coordinates;//nothing displayed
                if ($m_coordinates != NULL) {
                    $DB->setGeoTCard($row->card_id,$m_coordinates['lat'],$m_coordinates['lng']);
                } else {
                    $m_err_desc = sprintf("[%s-%s] Google could not find this Postcode",$mM,$y);

                    $m_error = array(
                        "err_desc" => $m_err_desc,
                        "err_code" => $row->client_code,
                        "err_comp" => $row->title,
                        "err_depo" => $row->description,
                        "err_post" => $m_postcode
                    );
                    $m_errors[] = $m_error;
                    $m_ignore[] = $row->card_id;
                }
                sleep(_GEOCODE_PAUSE);
            } else {
                $m_err_desc = sprintf("[%s-%s] Postcode is invalid please check",$mM,$y);
                $m_error = array(
                    "err_desc" => $m_err_desc,
                    "err_code" => $row->client_code,
                    "err_comp" => $row->title,
                    "err_depo" => $row->description,
                    "err_post" => $m_postcode
                );
                $m_errors[] = $m_error;
                $m_ignore[] = $row->card_id;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (count($m_errors) > 0) {
    $Emails->doGeocodeErrNotify($m_errors);
}
```

geocode.class.php

```
    class Geocode {

private $m_session = NULL;
private $m_security = NULL;

private $m_session_user;
private $m_session_pass;

private $m_key = _GMAP_KEY;
private $m_url = _GMAP_URL;
private $m_res = Array();

public function __construct($p_session,$p_security) 
{
    $this->m_session    = $p_session;
    $this->m_security   = $p_security;  

    $this->m_session_user   = $this->m_session->get('USR_AUTH');
    $this->m_session_pass   = $this->m_session->get('USR_PASS');

    if ($this->m_security->doLogin($this->m_session_user,$this->m_session_pass) <= 0) 
    { 
        return NULL;
        die; 
    } 
}

public function doGeocode($p_postcode)
{
    try {
    //  //$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(sprintf($this->m_url,$p_postcode,$this->m_key),0,TRUE); //OLD FOR V.2
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(sprintf($this->m_url,$p_postcode),0,TRUE);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo sprintf('Caught exception: %s', $e->getMessage());
        return NULL;
        die;
    }
    $st = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    if (strcmp($st, "200") == 0) 
    {
        $co = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
        $cs = preg_split("/[\s]*[,][\s]*/", $co);

        $this->m_res = Array(
                "lng" => $cs[0],
                "lat" => $cs[1],
                "alt" => $cs[2]
            );
        return $this->m_res;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

}

I would really appriciate if someone could help me please. Im guessing its something to do with the new url in my config file and the current xml not set properly for the sensor??

Answer (score 0):

My geocode stuff is still working fine just like this don't forget to use your own personal API key!

```
/**
* Geocode postcode to get long/lat used when adding suppliers and sites
* @param - $postcode - string - Input post code to geocode
* @return - $lat,$long - array - array containing latitude coords
*/
function geocode($postcode) {
    $postcode = urlencode(trim($postcode)); // post code to look up in this case status however can easily be retrieved from a database or a form post
    //$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$postcode."&sensor=false"; // the request URL you'll send to google to get back your XML feed
    define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.co.uk");
    define("KEY", "YOUR API KEY HERE");
    $base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;
    $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . $postcode;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
      // Successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
      $coordinatesSplit = explode(",", $coordinates);
      // Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
      return array("lat"=>$coordinatesSplit[1],"long"=>$coordinatesSplit[0]);
    } else {
      return array("lat"=>0,"long"=>0);
    }
}
```